# Identifying DIP-16 chip labeled 6880 8621?

Tags: identification

Image:

[image]

Couldn't find anything on Google, reverse image search also didn't help.

Comment: anton-tchekov - Hi, Do you have any more context you can add about that IC e.g. what equipment it was used in? Any idea about its possible functionality? If you do have more info, please edit the question to add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a version of the [MC6880](https://vikiwat.com/userfiles/productimages/10546/files/integralna-shema-mc6880-quad-three-state-bus-tranceiver-with-high-impedance-pnp-inputs-dip16-0.pdf) aka MC8T26A quad 3-state transceiver. The logo looks vaguely Eastern European to my eyes (could easily be wrong on that point).

[image]